# jpa2 db reverse engineering with bean validation annotations

Tags: java, jpa-2.0, bean-validation

I'm trying to generate JPA java classes from existing Oracle database. Generated classes contain JPA annotations like @Column(nullable=false, length=40). Is there any open source tool that would generate Java Bean Validation annotations as well (@NotNull @Size(max=40) in this case)?

Comment: It happens automatically in netbeans

Answer (score 1):

A standalone app that does attributes for you.  best option for quick solution : 
http://sourceforge.net/projects/minuteproject/

Eclipse has the Dali project.  I'm not sure if it will do the attributes for you : http://www.eclipse.org/webtools/dali/gettingstarted.php

Then, if you are using Hibernate & Maven, hibernate3-maven-plugin is an option too.